# Different species of sapiens, each one with their own superpower?

Tags: internal-consistency, technology, creature-design, super-powers, simulated-worlds

In a simulated world created by humans, a diversity of sapiens species have "powers", capacities that humans were not capable of creating before in reality.

**Question:**

I want to know if it was possible that a simulation of a planet, could create an organism superior to the humans in reality and if not what could I make to create a similar situation.

Comment: Just about anything is plausible if you're a good storyteller....

Comment: This question is too broad. By "simulation" - do you mean computer simulated worlds where laws of physics can be different?

Comment: It's conventional to wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer so that people from every time zone get a chance to weigh in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a reality where multiple universes exist and god-like beings evolved, these "simulations" could be full (or simulated) universes where the physical laws have been altered.

They don't have to be big to make a difference, such as Na "liking" F more than Cl.  No "table salt" could mean a completely different type of life evolves, maybe no life evolves, it's entirely up to you as the storyteller.

You can even make time a variable, so that an entire universe is created from Big Bang and ends in the Big Crunch in the matter of minutes to the observer, but the time within the test universe took many trillions of millennia for things to happen.

The exa-humans (or whatever they are called) doing the experiments would think of the beings within their simulated universes as we would amoeba: interesting forms of life, but expendable when it's time to end the simulation/clean the petri dish.

Also, a computer made by the "experimenters" could be so powerful as to create a simulation so realistic as to render it so realistic as to make it seem real to those inside the simulation (think The Matrix).  Beings that seem to be self-aware and able to make non-deterministic decisions could simply be bits and bytes, and not even realize it.

At this point, super-powers are just one variable in the cosmic equation that you, as the story teller, can create and set your own parameters for, without the necessity of realism outside your story.

This could even go so far as to one simulated being having a power like Deadpool, knowing that it's a simulation and then escaping the simulation.

Comment: But my history will be something like that, the issue I am having is to make the powers in the simulation according to the physical laws, because when the sapiens in the simulation "get out", they can make bodies, similar to the bodies in the simulation, because that will be their only advantage to the humans that have superior tech but in terms of modifications to the human body are so far behind (because the powers of the sapiens was a complete fluke of luck, it was not intentional).

Comment: I think that means you'll need a large amount of sapient escaping the simulation(s) with a wide variety of powers.  A large battle could ensue with only a handful remaining.  This handful could then, by reason of elimination, be the right group to have (a combination of) speed, strength, mental acuity, radiation resistance, etc, that specifically negates the superiority of the overseers, however that works out in your story.